# Added GMS to Android App For Location Services Now It Crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-location, android-gradle-plugin

I just added GMS to my app to use the LocationClient and now my app is crashing upon startup.  Looks like my main activity can no longer find my service which is where the location logic is handled.

I added the below line to my gradle dependencies in order to pull in gms.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
28 22:10:39.761    2885-2885/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nathan.allgood, PID: 2885
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/myname/appname/services/ActivityService;
```

Also have this in my manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
Nathan

EDIT: Added LogCat and Method where error happens

```
    /**
     * Bind this Activity to MyService
     */
    private void doBindService() {
        getActivity().bindService(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

11-28 22:53:59.502    2278-2278/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myname.appname, PID: 2278
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myname.appname.services.ActivityService
        at com.myname.appname.Activity1$OneFragment.automaticBind(Activity1.java:119)
        at com.myname.appname.Activity1$OneFragment.onResume(Activity1.java:105)
        at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1743)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1863)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5332)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2818)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5062)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 23:33:12.336    6335-6335/com.myname.appname E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class    'com.myname.appname.services.ActivityService', referenced from method   com.myname.appname.Activity1$OneFragment.doBindService
11-28 23:33:12.386    6335-6335/com.myname.appname E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myname.appname, PID: 6335
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myname.appname.services.ActivityService
        at com.myname.appname.Activity1$OneFragment.automaticBind(Activity1.java:119)
        at com.myname.appname.Activity1$OneFragment.onResume(Activity1.java:105)
        at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1743)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1863)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5332)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2779)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2818)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1407)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5062)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit 2:
I should also mention I am using Android Studio

SOLUTION!!!
Edit 3:
Following some advice from another stackoverflow post I did a 
gradlew clean and then gradlew build which seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: Please post your Logcat

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not post your code, look for "Caused by" in your logcat. Tell me why you use AsyncTask to get your Location?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't use an AsyncTask to get the location at all.  The location is acquired inside a service I have running.  I have posted the entire logcat above.